# open the hidden div if the relevant item is selected in the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to make a show hide based on the selection of the item in a select box,

The code is working fine where one issue is when the item is already selected, it does not open the div, i have to delect it and again select it to open the div.

here is the html and JS Code for this

```
<select name="licenseType" id="licenseType" class="licenseType" multiple>

              <option value="1" 
              SELECTED>Truck License</option>

              <option value="2" 
              >Car License</option>

              <option value="3" 
              SELECTED>Two Wheeler</option>

              <option value="4" 
              SELECTED>Four Wheeler</option>

              <option value="5" 
              >Six Wheeler</option>

              <option value="6" 
              SELECTED>Eight Wheeler</option>

              <option value="7" 
              class="special" SELECTED>Special License</option>

              <option value="8" 
              class="machine" >Machine Operator License</option>

            </select>
```

JS Code:

```
$(".specialLicense").hide('5000');
   $('select#licenseType').change(function () {
    if ($('option:selected', this).hasClass('special')) {
        $(".specialLicense").show('5000');
    } else {
        $(".specialLicense").hide('5000');
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, you have to trigger the `change` event manually once,

```
 $('select#licenseType').change(function () {
    if ($('option:selected', this).hasClass('special')) {
        $(".specialLicense").show('5000');
    } else {
        $(".specialLicense").hide('5000');
    }
  }).change();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WnrEW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the function on the page load too :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/WnrEW/)**

*jQuery :*

```
function select(){
     if ($('select#licenseType option:selected').hasClass('special')) {
        $(".specialLicense").show('5000');
    } else {
        $(".specialLicense").hide('5000');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    select();

    $('select#licenseType').change(function () {
       select();
   });
});
```